# Strict-Aliasing warnings and tcpdump example code

Tags: c, gcc, strict-aliasing

Simplifying the concept, the strict-aliasing rule states that an object should be accessed by a pointer of a compatible type or a pointer to `char`. That way, the compiler can make some assumptions about the code and make some optimizations.

Even though its interpretation can bring up some doubts and discussion, the rule itself isn't any state secret. So my questions are:

Why some respected organizations, which are maintained by experienced programmers, frequently submit codes which don't respect the strict aliasing rule? An example that I can give is `tcpdump`: On their website's [tutorial](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm) on `libpcap` there's an [example code](http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c) that apparently breaks the strict aliasing rules **several** times. I've seem many other codes that do so too, specially when handling network packets..
Did they just got lucky the compiler didn't completely broke their code so it got unnoticed? Do they rely on the user compiling with `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag? That would be a possibility considering some respectful programmers - I think Linus Torvalds himself for example, as I've seem on some mailing list about a Linux snippet that would break with strict aliasing enabled - don't really think the optimization gained with the strict aliasing compensates the kind of bad assumptions the compiler could make. Or is it just bad code and a bad practice that unfortunately is intrinsicate in the programming community?

The other question is about that `sniffex.c` code from [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c): Why even when compiled with `gcc -O5 -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-aliasing=1 sniffex.c -lpcap` `gcc 5.4.0` don't issue any warnings on the strict aliasing rules being broken? Is it just because it doesn't detect those type-punnings easily when they don't have the address operator `&`?

I feel bad about bringing this topic once again (since there are so many other questions about it) but even though I understand the rule I can't seem to understand why it is ignored so often in lots of places..

---

**EDIT:**

The snippets of the `tcpdump` example code that apparently breaks the strict aliasing rule are:

```
void got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{
...
/* declare pointers to packet headers */
const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet;  /* The ethernet header [1] */
const struct sniff_ip *ip;              /* The IP header */
const struct sniff_tcp *tcp;            /* The TCP header */
const char *payload;                    /* Packet payload */
...
/* define ethernet header */
ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);

/* define/compute ip header offset */
ip = (struct sniff_ip*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET);
...
/* define/compute tcp header offset */
tcp = (struct sniff_tcp*)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip);
...
/* define/compute tcp payload (segment) offset */
payload = (u_char *)(packet + SIZE_ETHERNET + size_ip + size_tcp);
...
```

There, they do some sort of overlaying with structures that represent the different parts of network packets to have an easier way to access each of the fields. In the bottom line, it uses several pointers that don't have an effective type of `u_char` (the original `packet` type) to access it, thus, I believe, violating the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Please add the actual parts of the code into the question itself! There is nothing apparent in 19kc of C code.

Comment: Also, no-strict-aliasing is somewhat easier in the Linux kernel as it doesn't use floating point!

Comment: For the first part of the question, I doubt we will be able to answer why other programmers did what they did. We can't read their thoughts anymore than you can. Check if the site has a forum/mail-list or the like and ask them directly.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I'm sorry! I should have posted the specific parts of the code that contains the issue before. I've included it now!

Comment: IMO this code is totally wrong. The prototype says `const u_char *packet` - how is one to know that the packet needs *alignment* beyond `sizeof (char)`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That prototype is from a callback function from the `libpcap` library itself. The buffer `packet` will point to a captured network packet, so one can expect it to at least have enough size to hold an ethernet header (if that's the link layer being used), and then the code (should) check the ethernet header field to see if the packet is an IP packet (in which case we can expect it to have at least enough size to hold also the IP header) and then it also checks the IP header field to see if it is a TCP packet (then we can expect another chunk of data for the TCP header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strict aliasing rule is controversial.

Bit of background:

Note that "the strict aliasing rule" is not a formal term, but it refers the the paragraph 6.5/6 regarding *effective type* and 6.5./7 regarding accessing data through a pointer. The latter paragraph is the actual strict aliasing rule and it has been part of C for as long as the language has been standardized, so its existence should actually not come as a shock to anyone. The text in 6.5./7 is nearly identical all the way from the ANSI-C drafts to C11.

However, this section was unclear in C90, because it focused on the type of the pointer used for the "lvalue access", rather than the type of the data actually stored there. Which made situations where you cast to void pointers unclear, such as when using `memcpy`, or when you are doing various forms of type punning.

In C99 there was some attempt to clarify this by introducing *effective type*. This didn't actually change the wording of the strict aliasing rule much, just made the interpretation somewhat clearer. (It still remains one of the hardest parts in the standard to understand.)

The original intent for the rule was to allow compilers to avoid weird worst-case assumptions, such as this example from the C99 rationale:

```
int a;
void f( double * b )
{
  a = 1;
  *b = 2.0;
  g(a);
}
```

If the compiler can assume that `b` is not pointing at `a`, which should be a sensible assumption to make given the wildly different types, then it can optimize the function to

```
a = 1;
*b = 2.0;
g(1); // micro-optimization, doesn't have to load `a` from memory
```

---

So even though the rule has been there all the time, it wasn't a problem before somewhere along C99, when the gcc compiler in particular decided to go haywire and *abuse* the cases where different effective types were used. For example this code makes perfect sense, yet violates strict aliasing:

```
uint32_t u32=0;
uint16_t* p16 = (uint16_t*)&u32; // grab the ms/ls word (endian-dependent)
*p16 = something;
if(u32)
  do_stuff();
```

The above would be very useful code in all manner of bit-twiddling and hardware-related programming. Most compilers will generate what the programmer expects, namely code that changes the ms/ls word of the 32 bit value then check if the function should be called.

However, since the above code is formally undefined behavior because of the strict aliasing violation, compilers like gcc might decide to abuse it and generate code that always removes the call to `do_stuff()` from the machine code, since it may assume that nothing in the code changes `u32` from having the value 0.

To dodge that unwanted compiler behavior, the programmer has to go out of their way. Either make the `u32` volatile so that the compiler is forced to read it - which blocks *all* optimizations on the variable and not just the undesired one. Or alternatively come up with a home-brewed union type containing one `uint32_t` and two `uint16_t`. Or possibly access the u32 byte per byte. Very inconvenient.

---

Therefore programmers tend to rebel against the strict aliasing rule and write code the relies on the compiler not making incredibly weird optimizations based on strict aliasing. There exists many valid cases when you want to break up a chunk of data in different parts, such as when de-serializing a block of raw data bytes.

For example if I receive serial data byte-by-byte and store it in an array of `uint8_t` that I, the programmer, know contains a `uint16_t`, I should be able to write code like `(uint16_t*)array` without the compiler making assumptions such as "oh look, this array is never used, lets optimize it away" or some other nonsense.

Most compilers will not go crazy but generate the expected code. But they are *allowed* to go crazy by the standard. And with the growing popularity of gcc in hardware-related programming, this is becoming a serious problem for the embedded industry, where hardware-related programming is an everyday task, rather than an exotic special case.

Overall, the standard committee has repeatedly failed to see this problem.

---

And then of course, a lot of programmers actually don't know about the strict aliasing rule in the first place, which is most often the explanation of why they write code violating it.

Comment: You either intended *"to allow"* or *"allowing"*, I chose the former for you. Change if I guessed wrong.

Comment: Very complete answer! Mind me asking if there are any ongoing discussions on the C standard committee on reformulating the strict aliasing rules to satisfy both compiler programmers and low-level hardware programmers? Sorry if that question goes too further away from the original discussion, just got curious since I'm now finding out there is this resistance from the programming community to abide by the original rule..

Comment: Making one variable volatile isn't enough. Volatile operations are guaranteed to happen, as they are almost I/O operations. But the volatile read could happen before the non volatile write.

Comment: AFAIK, the `volatile` qualifier means a variable's value can change at any time, something usually true when you deal with memory-mapped I/O. I'd think that the program would have to read the variable's value every time it had to use it, sort of solving the issue when the strict-aliasing optimizations are taking place in places it should not? I'm not sure what you meant with volatile read and non-volatile write, for some reason I think your statement reminds me more of atomic operations and race conditions.

Comment: @curiousguy It is the compilers job to ensure that the code gets executed as the programmer intended. In case of volatile variables, that means that they must be sequenced in the way specified by the source code. The C standard does not care about things like branch prediction, instruction cache or memory barriers. If side effects, such as accessing a volatile variable, are re-ordered, the compiler implementation is not conforming.

Comment: @curiousguy Similarly, the compiler is not allowed to change the sequencing of any variables. The "volatile read" `p16 = (uint16_t*)&u32;` will _always_ happen before the "non-volatile write" `*p16 = something;`. This is because of the semi colon at the end of the former, which marks a sequence point. The first write to `p16` is sequenced before the second one. The compiler is not allowed to do it differently.

Comment: @Lundin You don't understand. The semi colon is irrelevant. Volatile operations are not ordered WRT to internal state change, period. Volatile isn't a Java volatile, which might be what you want.

Comment: @curiousguy They are. Read the whole of C11 5.1.2.3 Program execution. It's the compiler's task to ensure that things such as memory barriers are present, despite of what some will have you believe.

Comment: @Lundin "_They are._" You absolutely don't get it. If your program has undefined behavior, then the behavior can't be deduced from the standard. You can't violate requirements and then quote the standard. "_Read the whole of C11 5.1.2.3_" Read it yourself. "_It's the compiler's task to ensure that things such as memory barriers are present_" No it isn't.

Comment: @curiousguy And where exactly did you find UB? 5.1.2.3/3 and 5.1.2.3/4 explicitly state the order of execution of a C program. Instead of just saying "no" perhaps quote some source?

Comment: @Lundin It's UB due to "the strict aliasing rule". It's the whole point of the question! 5.1.2.3 exactly says what I wrote. Volatile manipulations are side effects, non volatile write are not. There is no ordering.

Comment: "_Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
that does any of those operations are all side effects,
11) which are changes in the state of
the execution environment. Evaluation of an expression may produce side effects. At
certain specified points in the execution sequence called sequence points, all side effects
of previous evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations
shall have taken place._" You are confusing the external world and the "abstract machine", which is hidden.

Comment: @Lundin: Volatile operations have whatever semantics implementations define.  The Standard deliberately does not require that all conforming compilers be suitable for systems programming, but quality implementations suitable for such purposes for systems that may include features like DMA will refrain from register-caching anything that isn't qualified `register` or `restrict` across a volatile access.  An implementation that would require that things like DMA must be performed only with statically-allocated volatile-qualified storage should be regarded as being inferior to one which...

Comment: ...can use non-qualified storage if code does whatever is necessary to guard against *hardware* caching issues.

Answer (score 1):

Well I assume that you have not learnt C in the 70' with the K&R C... Not all code has been written in 21st century. The strict aliasing rule was **added** to C language to allow optimizing compiler to do better optimizations, and compilers programmers were clever enough to add the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag in order not to break legacy code.

What I mean here is that writing new code that breaks the strict aliasing rule is indeed bad(*). But there are tons of legacy code that had been written before the adoption of the strict aliasing rule, in applications that *just do the job*, tcpdump is a simple example of this.

---

(*) Well for some low level code, mainly when dealing with network data and when you need true low level optimization, it can make sense to willingly break the strict aliasing rule and document that. The alternatives are only to either uselessly copy buffers back and forth, or use assembly language that loses any portability. But that should never exist in *normal* code.

Comment: Thank you Serge! That last observation of yours is something I've been thinking ever since I've learned about strict aliasing. It just sounds so impractical to use `memcpy` or `unions` on those cases (`unions` would even be a worse candidate when the position of each structure is different on the buffer). So it's an overall sense among experienced programmers that we can willingly break that rule (adding the pertinent compiler flags and documenting it) when we deal with such situations?

Comment: @murphsghost `memcpy` is optimized completely away by GCC when it is not needed.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's true! But may I ask something? Is that optimization something well-defined in the standards or is it something `gcc` came up with for situations like this one?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Also, it sounds like it will be a bit of a leap of faith to trust `gcc` to optimize it away, because otherwise you'll have the overhead of a memory allocation and memory copy for each different pointer you try to use for accessing the buffer right?

Comment: @murphsghost my memcpy comment is for simple values. I am not sure it would be optimized for complex structures like the ones above.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I know GCC is clever than me! And indeed for any medium to high level programming the strict aliasing rule is fine, and I happily rely on the compiler to produce acceptable code. But when I get a struct correctly aligned in the middle of a char buffer (read from a file or a socket) and I cannot say that it just lies there but shall memcopy it to a true struct, it really bothers me.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I see, that sounds like a more straight forward optimization people can rely on. When it comes to complex data structures I think I'd be a bit concerned if the compiler would figure out the right thing to do. Also, it would add complexity to the code (figuring out how much memory should be "copied", allocating memory before the `memcpy` call, "freeing" the memory allocated), though it would make the code compliant

Comment: @SergeBallesta To be honest, I've some code around that violates the strict aliasing rule and I'm still trying to figure out what to do with it. I'm between either rewriting the non-compliant code to use `memcpy`, which would be a bit tricky on some parts, or simply compiling those particular C files with the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flags, while compiling the compliant ones without the flag. I think I'm increasingly agreeing with the programmers that believe this rule needs some rethinking.. :p

Comment: @murphsghost: Document a requirement for `-fno-strict-aliasing`.  If you ever get a compiler with sane aliasing logic, it will be able to optimize more effectively than would be possible with `memcpy`.  Further, `memcpy` can avoid aliasing rules when reading things of arbitrary type, but not when writing.  Today's gcc may not exploit all of the "optimizations" that would be allowed by carrying Effective Types through `memcpy`, but who knows what future versions will do.

Answer (score 0):

By the time the first C Standard was written in 1989, it was apparent that C implementations were being used for many purposes which had different needs, and on many platforms which had different abilities.  People writing C implementations for targeting application fields and platforms where it made sense to provide features and guarantees beyond what the Standard would end up requiring had done so without being compelled to do so by any standard.  Code which relied upon such features or guarantees would only be portable to platforms where support for them was practical, but absent any foreseeable likelihood of wanting to run the code on platforms that couldn't support such features, that did not imply any sort of defect.  Further, the authors of the Standard didn't think it necessary to explicitly mandate behaviors which implementations would have had to go out of their way, or at least engage in willful blindness, *not*
to provide.

Under C89, if a function receives a pointer to some storage from outside
code and accesses it using two different non-character pointer types,
behavior would be equivalent to accessing members of a union containing
those types.  Depending upon the types and how they are used, the behavior
may be either defined by the Standard, or it may be Implementation-Defined;
an implementation may describe conditions which would need to be upheld to
yield deterministic behavior, but if an implementation describes how things
are stored and *doesn't* specify any cases where writing a union member (via
any means) and reading another (via any means) would yield behavior other
than what would be implied by their storage formats, their behavior would
be *defined* by their storage formats.

The authors of gcc have somehow decided that when the authors of the Standard describe Undefined Behavior as "non-portable or erroneous", they mean "erroneous".  They further think that when the authors found that there may be *some* kinds of implementation for which no forms of type punning beyond those mandated would have sufficient value to justify the cost of support, they were making a cost/value judgment applicable to all implementations.

I don't think many programmers would have any objection to the idea that a compiler should presume that pointers to things of different types won't alias *when there is no evidence that such things might alias*, nor even to the idea that compilers shouldn't have to look *very far* to find such evidence.  Aliasing issues should only matter would be when a compiler sees two operations upon an object that appear to be consecutive, but another operation between them affects the same object.  In code like the above, a compiler should have no reason to get tripped up by aliasing issues, since the use of pointer casts would suggest to any compiler that isn't willfully blind that compilers should only regard actions before and after the cast as "consecutive" if it can see that aliasing would be impossible even in the absence of rules against it.

**Addendum**

Issues of aliasing don't really have anything to do with "programmer intent".  Outside of compiler testing or other contrived scenarios, programmers essentially **never** intend that code behave in a fashion inconsistent with the behavior produced by having all lvalue accesses operate upon underlying storage in execution order.  There are some application fields where such behavior would, for all practical purposes, always be equivalent to some other behaviors that could be realized more efficiently, and there are some application fields where the latter alternatives would be observably and disastrously different.

Consider the two functions:

```
int i1;
int test1(float *fp)
{
  i1 = 2;
  *fp = 1.0f;
  return i1;
}

int i2;
int test2(int *ip)
{
  i1 = 2;
  *(float*)ip = 1.0f;
  return i1;
}
```

In either case, the intent of the code is to behave as though storing the
representation of `int` value 2 into the storage occupied by `i1` or `i2`,
then storing the representation of the `float` value `1.0f` into the address
passed from outside code, and finally reading as `int` the value in the
storage occupied by `i1` or `i2`and returning it to the caller.  What is
different between the two programs is not the intent, but rather whether
there is anything between the write of `i1`/`i2` and the read thereof that
would suggest that anything might have affected it.  I would agree with the C89 Standards Committe (who used a similar example) that there is nothing in `test1()` to suggest that `float *fp` might--despite its type--actually hold the address of an `int`.  On the other hand, I would untenable the notion that there is nothing in the second example to suggest that `int *ip` might hold the address of an `int`.  Note that programmer "intent" plays no part in the analysis--the question is purely whether there is absolutely nothing between the integer write and read that would suggest that an `int` might have been affected.

Nothing in the rationale given for C89's aliasing rules or subsequent ones suggests that they were ever intended to make programmers jump through hoops to achieve useful behaviors.  Instead, the rationale is predicated upon the observation that there are many cases where such optimizations could be applied harmlessly and compilers should be allowed to apply them in such cases.  The authors wanted to ensure that operations which need to interpret data as sequences of bytes would work, but otherwise figured that because different application fields have different needs, compilers should be free to use aliasing rules that were appropriate to their intended field.

Comment: There are extremely serious issues with Linus' idea that the compiler should use knowledge of aliasing to avoid breaking code, and generate desired behavior where what is desired is very clear. It means that code behavior is not constrained by some abstract idea of correctness on the platform (which is distinct from correctness in the language standard) but by the ability of the compiler to see intent, which is affected by the amount of code available for flow analysis, f.ex. This means that by moving code to a different, out of line (out of view) function, you can break code. Very un-C/C++!

Comment: @curiousguy: As I would write the rules, a pointer cast would open a window of opportunity to use the object as a new type until the first of (1) an operation using the object via pointer not derived from a pointer that had been cast to the new type, (2) code enters a function in which (1) occurs, (3) code enters a bona fide loop in which (1) occurs [not counting "do {} while(0)" loops.  Add in a clarification to the Common Initial Sequence rule that requires that if one piece of code uses S1 to write a member and another piece uses S2 to read it, then a complete union definition...

Comment: ...containing both types must be visible either at the place it is written, or at the place it is read.  A compiler with non-broken aliasing logic should be able to flag an access to a CIS member as a potential access to the corresponding CIS members of all visible union types.  Since programmers don't generally declare unions of arbitrary structures if they won't need to be accessed in such fashion, the performance cost should be far lower than `-fno-strict-aliasing` which would otherwise be necessary to make the CIS useful.

Comment: @curiousguy: I can't think of many useful optimizations which would be blocked by the rules as I describe them, nor can I think of many things that would be possible under `-fno-strict-aliasing` which would not be possible under the rules as described.  Adding some directives to specifically say "within this region of code, this pointer needs to be able to access things of type X [or 'arbitrary type']" would be better, but I can't think of any good syntax which would allow code to be used with either new compilers or with existing compilers and `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: @curiousguy: Also, I'm curious in what situations you think moving code out-of-line would break things?  Normally the problem is the reverse, since compilers are required to make pessimistic assumptions about code they can't see.  A compiler might not have particular knowledge that some function it calls is going to cast a `float*` to an `int*` and read it, but it should have no reason for assuming that function won't read and write things of those types unless it has particular information to that effect, and if a function casts `float*` to `int*` it shouldn't report that it doesn't...

Comment: ...write to `float*` unless the compiler can everything that is done with the resulting `int*` pointers and can tell that they are not written.

Comment: @curiousguy: BTW, the issue of "programmer intent" is a red herring.  Outside of contrived scenarios like compiler tests, C programs which are meant to be executed **never** intend any behavior contrary to what would be achieved by treating all lvalue accesses as operating upon the contents of addressable storage.  There may be some questions about the full range of scenarios where an implementation suitable for a particular application field might be called upon to yield that behavior, but there's no question about what the intended behavior would be in any case that might arise.

Comment: @curiousguy: C would be better for both number-crunching and low-level programming if rather than try to come up with "compromise" aliasing rules, it instead said that if a program includes one directive, a compiler may assume no storage that has ever been used as any type will *ever* be used as any other during its lifetime, and if it included another directive compilers must allow arbitrary-type aliasing if code uses certain patterns to make it "obvious".  Different fields have different needs, and any "compromise" will make the language less sutable for some purposes.